# Warning: file_put_contents in plugin-list.php and PluginListGenerator.php in Magento 2.4.2 during compilation

Tags: compilation, magento2.4.2, warning

While compilation the Magento 2.4.2 experienced following error

Warning: file_put_contents(ProjectName/generated/metadata/primary|global|plugin-list.php):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ProjectName\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php on line 414

Answer (score 15):

To fix above error, kindly follow the below steps

Open `PluginListGenerator.php` file located at `vendor/magento/framework/Interception.`

Go to line no 414 or find the word “`scopePriorityScheme`” in `PluginListGenerator.php` file.

Replace the line

```
"$cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;" 
with
"$cacheId = implode('-', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "-" . $this->cacheId;"
```

This time compilation command, `bin/magento setup:di:compile` should work

Comment: in my case: it is on line 158 in magento2.4.1 EE

Comment: In 2.4.6, its line 156. Same fix.

Answer (score 4):

Solution for Failed to Open Stream Error While Compiling PluginListGenerator.php in Magento 2.4.1
Open `PluginListGenerator.php` file located at `vendor/magento/framework/Interception.`

Replace the line

```
$cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;

with below:

$cacheId = implode('-', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "-" . $this->cacheId;
```

Save the `PluginListGenerator.php` file.
Now your `“bin/magento setup:di:compile”` command will run successfully without any error.

That’s it!

If you have any question regarding this error or its solution, feel free to mention them in the Comments section below.

I’m here to help you out.

Do share the solution with Magento Community via social media.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

To fix error `"In ErrorHandler.php line 61: Warning: file_put_contents(/magento2/generated/metadata/primary|global|plugin-list.php): Failed to o pen stream: No such file or directory in \magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListG enerator.php on line 414"`

Inside function `public function write(array $scopes): void` of file `vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginListGenerator.php`

Replace the line

```
$cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;
```

to

```
$cacheId = implode('-', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "-" . $this->cacheId;
```

After this, I have to execute the below commands to show the content on main website

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered during compilation in Magento 2.4.2 indicates that the file `ProjectName/generated/metadata/primary|global|plugin-list.php` could not be created because the directory does not exist. To resolve this issue, you can follow these steps:

1. Ensure the `generated` directory exists: Verify that the `generated` directory exists in the root of your Magento installation. If it doesn't exist, create it manually.
2. Set proper permissions: Make sure the `generated` directory and its subdirectories have the correct permissions. You can set the appropriate permissions using the following command:

   ```bash
   chmod -R 777 generated
   ```

   Note: It's important to ensure the correct ownership and permissions are set according to your server environment. The above command is an example, but you may need to adjust it based on your specific server configuration.
3. Clear the generated code: Remove any existing generated code files to ensure a clean regeneration process. You can use the following command:

   ```bash
   rm -rf generated/*
   ```
4. Recompile your code: Now, recompile your Magento code by running the following command:

   ```bash
   bin/magento setup:di:compile
   ```

   This command will regenerate the necessary files, including the `plugin-list.php` file that was causing the error.
5. Verify the issue is resolved: After the compilation process completes, check if the error is resolved. If the `plugin-list.php` file is successfully generated, the compilation process should complete without any warnings or errors.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the error related to the missing `plugin-list.php` file during the compilation process in Magento 2.4.2.